# Peri peri sauce

Tags: canning

I’m a bit confused,  do we leave the bottles in boiling water for 20 min before putting the sauce in and then seal the bottle and put it back in boiling water for another 10 min, or do we put the sealed bottles in a pot and boil them for 10 min.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when canning there are two boiling steps:

1. Boiling the bottles before adding the stuff you are canning is to "sterilize" the bottles, and provide heat that helps prevent the bottle from cracking when hot items are added to the bottle.
2. The second boiling is to help create the hermetic seal by heating the lids and the bottle, and also to ensure that the contents have been re-heated after pouring, so that any contaminants picked up in the transfer process have been killed.